# What is better in sIFR 3 beta than sIFR 2?

Tags: javascript, css, flash, sifr

What is better in sIFR 3 beta than sIFR 2 ? What is benefit of using sIFR 3 over 2 ? I need details on differences .

Which is easy to implement and to maintain?

in my new projcet i want to use sIFR so which vesion should be choose and why ? I want to make my site compatible with al a Grade browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sIFR 2 is ancient, has a wrong approach to rendering text, uses Flash 6 so has lower rendering quality, and is generally broken.

Comment: is sIFR 3 has better rendering speed than sIFR2 ?

Answer (score 1):

sIFR 3 supports Opera now. It also has improved CSS load detection, which is disabled by default, but helps in making sIFR replace elements faster in Safari and Opera.

sIFR is worth a gander.

Comment: what is "CSS load detection" is it helful for IE and Firefox?